# PGFPlots - How to override "`no markers`" in `pgfplotsset`

Tags: pgfplots

I disabled the markers in my default settings with:

```
\pgfplotsset{every axis/.append style={
             label style={font=\small},
             tick label style={font=\small},
             no markers,
             grid
     },
     ...
 }
```

and I thought when I add `only marks` to the settings, it will override it. It almost works but ignores the marks setting as seen here (I added `no markers` explicitly to simplify the example):

```
\begin{axis}[xlabel={Cost}, ylabel={Error}]
    \addplot[color={red}, mark={x}, no markers, only marks]
        coordinates {
            (2,-2.8559703)
            (3,-3.5301677)
            (4,-4.3050655)
            (5,-5.1413136)
            (6,-6.0322865)
            (7,-6.9675052)
            (8,-7.9377747)
        }
        ;
\end{axis}
```

As you can see, the marks are not `x` but the default shape. So how should I override `no markers` correctly when those are set in my default `pgfplotsset`?

[image: no markers vs only marks]

Comment: Delete option `no markers` in `axis` options.

Comment: I put that in just to showcase it in an example. The `no markers` option is in my global `pgfplotsset`.

Comment: I see. However, if you would provide an MWE (Minimal Working Example), a small complete document, than question would be more clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can disable/overwrite the global `no markers` setting by providing suitable options to `every axis plot post` style which can either be added to the `axis` or the `\addplot` options.

```
% used PGFPlots v1.16
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{
        every axis/.append style={
            label style={font=\small},
            tick label style={font=\small},
            no markers,
            grid,
        },
     }
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xlabel={Cost},
        ylabel={Error},
%        % if you want to disable the `only marks` setting for *all* the `\addplot` command of this plot
%        every axis plot post/.append style={
%            only marks,
%            mark=x,
%        },
    ]
        \addplot [
            color={red},
            every axis plot post/.append style={
                only marks,
                mark=x,
            },
        ] coordinates {
            (2,-2.8559703)
            (3,-3.5301677)
            (4,-4.3050655)
            (5,-5.1413136)
            (6,-6.0322865)
            (7,-6.9675052)
            (8,-7.9377747)
        };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]